# DrRacket help in writing a function to extract a RegE from RES type

Tags: racket, eval, call, substitution

I'm using lang pl for this.

I have the following data-types:

```
(define-type RES
[RES_Bool Boolean]
[RegV Bit-List]
[FunV Symbol RegE])
```

and these 2 functions:

```
(: RegV->bit-list : RES -> Bit-List)
;; extract a bit-list from RES type
(define (RegV->bit-list r)
  (cases r
    [(RegV bl) bl]
    [else (error 'RegV->bit-list "Given wrong type of RES" r)]
    )
  )

(: RegV->boolean : RES -> Boolean)
;; extract a boolean from RES type
(define(RegV->boolean res)
  (cases res
    [(RES_Bool b) b]
    [else (error 'RegV->boolean "Given wrong type of RES ~s" res)]))
```

I wanna write a new function for `[FunV Symbol RegE]`
I tried to do it like this:

```
(: RegV->RegE : RES -> RegE)
;; extract a RegE from RES type
(define(RegV->RegE res)
  (cases res
    [(FunV Symbol RegE) RegE]
    [else (error 'RegV->RegE "Given wrong type of RES ~s" res)]))
```

but this won't work, any help would be appriciated

Comment: What was the error? 
(remember that only a few has `pl` installed)

Comment: Should `RegV->RegE` be named `FunV->RegE` instead?